# Call a std::function class member with std::mem_fn

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, mem-fun

My plan is to build several listener classes which own predefined "callback hooks".

In the example below class `Foo` has a "callback hook" called `onChange`. It will be set to a default callback function during construction. It can also be set to an arbitrary function which provides the correct interface, like shown with the object `f1` and the function `callback()`.

The problem is when I want to call the object member `onChange` inside the for-loop the compiler says that I provide to much arguments. i am aware of the problem that i don't provide a member function to the `std::mem_fn` but instead an object member which is a function wrapper.

How do I manage to pass the argument to the `std::function` member object of class `Foo` without using `std::bind` and use `std::mem_fn` instead like shown in the example?

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo()
  {
    // default callback
    onChange = [](int value)
               -> void { std::cerr << "Foo::onChange( " << value << " )" << std::endl; };
  }

  // class destructor
  virtual ~Foo() {}

  std::function<void(int value)> onChange;

};


void callback(int value)
{
  std::cerr << "callback( " << value << " )" << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
  Foo f0;
  Foo f1;
  f1.onChange = callback;

  auto vec = std::vector<Foo>();
  vec.push_back(f0);
  vec.push_back(f1);

  auto func_wrapper = std::mem_fn( &Foo::onChange );

  for (auto f : vec)
  {
    func_wrapper(f, 42);
  }
}
```

Comment: `mem_fn` doesn't do what you think it does, when passed a pointer-to-member-variable (as opposed to pointer-to-member-function). The resulting object's `operator()` takes one parameter - a pointer or reference to `Foo` - and returns the value of the corresponding member. It does not call `operator()` on that member.

Comment: `auto func_wrapper = [](Foo& f, int n) {return f.onChange(n); }` Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: why you don't want `std::bind` ?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for your answer! Then all i have to do is use `func_wrapper(f)(42)` instead of `func_wrapper(f, 42)`.

Comment: @PiotrS. I just want to avoid bind, because i would have to call bind with every iteration. When i use `std::mem_fun` than i just need to call the resulting `func_wrapper` everytime.

Comment: you talk about using a placeholder for the Foo object?

Comment: "just want to avoid bind, because i would have to call bind with every iteration." There is nothing wrong in calling `std::bind` with every iteration.